# How do I select specific cells in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I need to select specific cells on an excel sheet in vba. For example the code should be able to select a5, a10, a15. I do not want the cells in between them, just the ones I listed. Is there a specific function that will do this? It seems like .Range could only take start cell and ending cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use this:     `Range("A5,A10,A15").Select`

To add additional cells, just use more commas.

Alternately, you can utilize the [Union method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) to join multiple range objects into a single Range object.

Note that it is generally not a good idea to select cells in VBA as nearly everything can be done without selection. This is a frequent mistake made by people new to VBA due to generated macros (Record Macro) recreating what you do rather than the result you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. It seems likes I am doing this correct. The issue I am facing is that when I concatenate multiple cells into a String variable (mycells) and use it in Range(mycells).Select, the macro gives me an error and I believe it has to do with the String being able to handle only 255 characters.

Comment: That's correct. In that case, use Union. For example, you could do something like this: `Union(Range( _
        "A23,A29,A34,B35,C38,C33,B32,B31,C31,K36,I31,L25,J26,H28,G35,E38,F32,F27,F21,C17,C15,C10,A11,F18,E19,I19,J19,J15,I13,M13,A1,A3"), Range("A5,A7,B6,B5,C5,C4,C7,C13,B13,B18,C21,H22,H11,L16,E30,C28,C24,E25,E15,E10,F14,H16,J11,H5,G6,F6,E3,D8,A13,A19")).Select`

Comment: @DanielCook Unless some behaviour has changed that I am not aware of, the `Union` method has been available since Excel VBA was born?

Comment: @AndyG You're probably right. I actually wasn't familiar with the method and indicated the time frame only because of the MSDN article that only had an article for it for 2010 and 2013. A brief search pulls up information from Excel 2003 and 2007 as well. I'll remove the note about availability.